# is it possible to create a camera web app with js for a smartphone that has just the high resolution of a native app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, camera

is it possible to create a camera web app with js or ReactJS for a smartphone that produces an image that has just the high resolution of a native app?

The results I got so far with the knowledge I have looked blurry and grainy. I want at least to read the letters (12px Font height) on a DIN A4 paper. I want to use the rear camera.

https://codesandbox.io/embed/agitated-ardinghelli-94ikve?file=/src/index.js&codemirror=1

I tried:

- Using imagecapture and getUserMedia.
- Set image type to PNG and TIFF (instead of JPEG)
- Set resolution of video higher
- I could post process the image with opencv but the quality of the original image is so blurry to begin (see the sandbox above), but it won't be feasible to sharpen the image

If it's not possible, does anyone know what the limiting factor is?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using `imageCapture.takePhoto()`? See https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/image-capture/grab-frame-take-photo.html for instance?